# How to open a terminal inside a sub-directory from django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, terminal, subprocess

I am learning django. I am stuck with this problem.

I want to open a new terminal and execute a command in it. Here is the code that I used to do it.

`run(["gnome-terminal", "--", "sh", "-c", f"espeak -ven+m1 -f {file_name.name} -w {fbh}.wav "])`

I have written the above code in my views.py file. Here, `{file_name.name}` is the name of the text file I take as input from the user `{fbh}` is the name of the generated audio file.

Everything works perfectly but the problem is that the terminal opens in `auto_generation` directory and executes the code namely, `espeak -ven+m1 -f {file_name.name} -w {fbh}.wav` there but I want that it should open in `media` directory and execute the code there. `media` is a sub-directory of the  `auto_generation` directory.

Can someone please suggest me what changes I should do to the above command so that the new terminal opens in `media` directory instead of `auto_generation` directory?

As I already said I am new to django and some help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can always add `cd` to your command to change to other directory (`cd media && espeak ...`) - is that what you want?..

Comment: @SUTerliakov Can you tell me what changes should I do in the code? I know I can use cd but how should I code it?

Comment: Is `run(["gnome-terminal", "--", "sh", "-c", f"cd media && espeak -ven+m1 -f {file_name.name} -w {fbh}.wav "])` what you need? Also if you just need file from that directory, then `cd` is overhead: use `run(["gnome-terminal", "--", "sh", "-c", f"espeak -ven+m1 -f media/{file_name.name} -w media/{fbh}.wav "])`

Answer (score 0):

run this
to change directory

```
cd ~/media
```

and run your commands.

you can learn more how to using terminal
[command-line-tutorial](https://www.learnenough.com/command-line-tutorial)

Comment: I know how to change directory that is not my question. I have made my problem clearer perhaps now you will understand it. Please tell me what should I write in the code.